# algorithm : what's the relationship between k and n?

Tags: algorithm

To calculate the value of a^n:

method1:

```
  result = 1;
  for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
      result *= a;
```

if improved using method2:

```
result = a;
for(int i = 1; i <=k; i++)
    result = result * result;
```

How can I deduce the relationship between k and n? and why?
Thanks!

Comment: k is before n in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case result = a^n, in second case result = a^(2^k), so 2^k = n and k = logn. Of course this is correct only for n which are powers of 2.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to do [exponentiation by squaring](http://gsourcecode.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/algo-math-expsq/).

Obviously, for powers of 2, k = log_2 n.

Answer (score 0):

i think 
in first case the  a, a^2 , a^3..a^n
in second case it is a^2,a^4,A^8......A^(2^k)